# How to use proper loop in Ansible uri module

Tags: ansible

I'm using the [Ansible uri module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) to trigger the [pfSense API](https://github.com/jaredhendrickson13/pfsense-api).
Now I want to create firewall rules in a task (code is truncated).

```
---
# tasks file for creating firewall rules

- name: "Create firewall rules"
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ pf_hostname }}/api/v1/firewall/rule"
    method: "POST"
    body: "{ \
          \"client-id\": \"{{ pf_user }}\", 
            \"client-token\": \"{{ pf_password }}\",
            \"type\": \"{{ pf_fw_type_01 }}\",
            \"interface\": \"{{ pf_fw_interface_01 }}\",
          }"
```

The vars file looks like this.

```
---
# vars file for creating firewall rules

# Authentication
pf_hostname: "pfsense.local"
pf_user: "admin"
pf_password: "pfsense"

# Rule 01
pf_fw_type_01: "pass"
pf_fw_interface_01: "wan"
```

How can I now repeat the task without unnecessary redundancy (e.g. with loop) for other rules?
I only come up with the following idea, but it doesn't seem ideal to me.

```
  loop: 
    - "{{ item.client-id: {{ pf_user }}, item.type: {{ pf_fw_type_01 }} }}"
    - "{{ item.client-id: {{ pf_user }}, item.type: {{ pf_fw_type_02 }} }}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about putting the rules as a dynamic parameter in the list?
For example, here's like.

**vars.yml**

```yaml
---
# vars file for creating firewall rules

# Authentication
pf_hostname: "pfsense.local"
pf_user: "admin"
pf_password: "pfsense"

rules:
  - num: 01
    type: "pass"
    pf_fw_interface: "wan"

  - num: 02
    type: "pass"
    pf_fw_interface: "wan"
```

**playbook**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {
            "client-id": "{{ pf_user }}",
            "client-token": "{{ pf_password }}",
            "type": "{{ item.type }}",
            "interface": "{{ item.pf_fw_interface }}"
          }
      loop: "{{ rules }}"
```

**result**

```
$ ansible-playbook main.yml
(snip)

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'type': 'pass', 'pf_fw_interface': 'wan'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "client-id": "admin",
        "client-token": "pfsense",
        "interface": "wan",
        "type": "pass"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'type': 'pass', 'pf_fw_interface': 'wan'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "client-id": "admin",
        "client-token": "pfsense",
        "interface": "wan",
        "type": "pass"
    }
}
(snip)
```